# New products widget not sorting by creation date

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, widgets

I'm using the following code in my magento store to have a few new products on the main page of the store.

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="all_products" products_count="6"
  column_count="6" cache_lifetime="1" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

The annoying part is that I have 3 "magical" products (old as hell) stuck in this widget. No matter what, they continue to be there. This widget is for **new products**, so it should show only the most recent products added to the store, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it *should* sort all products by creation date. This is the code used for `display_type="all_products"`:

```
    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
        ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
        ->setCurPage(1)
    ;
```

This means, your magically stuck products seem to have a creation date in the future. You can only change it directly in the `catalog_product_entity` database table.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this code:
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="40" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}

Comment: in products count = "40" template ... use the number of products you want to display.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but what I really want are the recently added products. So that's why "all_products".

I work around this by duplicate those products and delete the old ones.